# How to implement a callback in a Fragment starting a Thread?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I try to close a ProgressDialog via Callback from Thread to fragment, but I don't know which reference I need to pass.

Some where in my Fragment I do the following:

```java
 c_thread_connectToDevice = new c_Thread_ConnectToDevice(UserSelectedDevice, 
 sFinalDonglePassword, getActivity());
 if(UserSelectedDevice != null){
 c_thread_connectToDevice.start();
 mProgessDialog.setTitle(R.string.ProgressDialog_Fragmentsetpassword_Title);
mProgessDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ProgressDialog_Fragmentsetpassword_Message));
 mProgessDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
 mProgessDialog.show();
```

The Callback is:

```java
public void dismissProgressDialog(){
        mProgessDialog.dismiss();

        if(!c_thread_connectToDevice.isbConnectionState()){
            tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Mercedes_RED, null));
            tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setText(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_ConnectionFailed);
        }else {
            tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setText(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_ConnectionSucces);
            tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Mercedes_GREEN, null));
        }

    }
```

In my Thread the I use the following Code:

```java
private WeakReference<Activity> weakReference;
...
 dismissProgressDialog();
...
private void dismissProgressDialog(){
        Activity activity = weakReference.get();
        activity.dismissProgressDialog();
    }
```

I know this could not work. But what is the right thing to pass?

Comment: you cannot call a method inside an `Activity` like this. Maybe you can pass the `ProgressDialog` object to the method and call the `dismiss()` there

Comment: Your weak reference holds a reference for an Activity instance which doesn't have the"dismissProgressDialog" method in it. you can hold a weak reference to your fragment class which implements this method. Anyway, I don't recommend you to do this thing, try to think about how to generify your code

Comment: Like I said, I know it is not working with a reverence to an Activity, I just did it to show what I want to do.
What do I need to pass for the reference to the Fragment?
`this` is of cause not working, but what do I need to send?

Comment: you are probably not going to be able to close a progress dialog from a thread, as it will probably require that you call it from the main thread and not a background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Zach Bublil told me, brought me to this solution.

```java
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
c_thread_connectToDevice = new c_Thread_ConnectToDevice(UserSelectedDevice, sFinalDonglePassword, c_Fragment_RoutineStartConnection_setpassword.this);
if(UserSelectedDevice != null){
c_thread_connectToDevice.start();
mProgessDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
mProgessDialog.setTitle(R.string.ProgressDialog_Fragmentsetpassword_Title);
mProgessDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ProgressDialog_Fragmentsetpassword_Message));
mProgessDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgessDialog.show();
```

## CallBack

```java
public void dismissProgressDialog(){
   mProgessDialog.dismiss();
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      if(!c_thread_connectToDevice.isbConnectionState()){
         tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Mercedes_RED, null));
       
      tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setText(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_ConnectionFailed);
       }else {
           tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setText(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_ConnectionSucces);
           tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Mercedes_GREEN, null));
              }
          }
        });
```

## InsideFragment

```java
private c_Thread_ConnectedToBluetoothDevice c_thread_connectedToBluetoothDevice;

public c_Thread_ConnectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device, String sFinalDonglePassword, c_Fragment_RoutineStartConnection_setpassword reference) {
        this.mBluetoothDevice = device;
        this.sFinalDonglePassword =sFinalDonglePassword;
        this.reference = reference;
    }
...
dismissProgressDialog();
...
 private void dismissProgressDialog(){
        reference.dismissProgressDialog();
    }
```

What is difficult for me to understand is, why I need to run the callback Text editions on mainthread. If I don't do that there is an exception to "Only the original thread creating the view..." but this is maybe caused by

```java
tools:context=".c_RoutineStartConnection"
```

which I used in the Fragment layout for better usability.